# Gibt es das Wort "manchmals"

Tags: colloquial, varieties

Manchmal hab ich die Form vom Wort "manchmal" als "manchmals" gehört, und eine Googlesuche ergibt auch einige Treffer. Ist dies nur eine Fehlschreibung oder ist es regional bedingt? Umgangssprachlich? Ich finde das Wort im Duden oder Wahrig nicht.

Wenn es einen Schreibfehler sein sollte, dann müßte der Fehler eine Ursache haben, z. B. dass manche Leute tatsächlich so sagen.  Oder?

Comment: Ich tippe auch auf einen Regionalismus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja, das Wort gibt es. Immerhin kann ich es klar und deutlich in der von dir selbst geschriebenen Frage lesen.

Weder der Duden noch der Wahrig oder irgend ein anderes Wörterbuch erhebt den Anspruch eine vollständige Liste aller deutschen Wörter zu enthalten. Auch die *Gitarrensaite* und die *Windelbox* stehen in keinem Wörterbuch, und trotzdem wird niemand an der Existenz dieser Wörter zweifeln. Oder suche mal »Brexit« im Duden oder Wahrig .

In Österreich und der Schweiz ist neben dem Wort »öfter« auch »öfters« in Gebrauch, wobei »öfters« als Synonym für »häufig« gebraucht wird:

> Lisa geht *öfters* in diesen Club.
>   Lisa geht *häufig* in diesen Club.

Und nach demselben Schema wird aus »manchmal« »manchmals«:

> *Manchmals* geht sie mir furchtbar auf den Geist.

(Quelle für diesen Satz: [dict.tu-chemnitz.de](http://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?o=302;iservice=de-en-ex;query=Manchmals), also ein Wörterbuch, publiziert von einer deutschen Universität.)

**Ist es eine Fehlschreibung?**
Das ist Definitionssache. Wenn jedes Wort, das nicht in einem Wörterbuch auffindbar ist, als fehlerhaft bewertet wird, dann ja. Dann ist aber auch der *Brexit* eine Fehlschreibung.

**Regional bedingt?**
Möglicherweise. Ich höre das hier in Österreich relativ oft, und lese es auch manchmal (selten, aber eben doch ab und zu mal) hier in Österreich. Da aber auch die Uni in Chemnitz in einem Deutsch-Wörterbuch dieses Wort verwendet, gibt es mindestens zwei Regionen, in denen das Wort gängig ist.

**Umgangssprachlich?**
Ich halte die Grenze zwischen Umgangssprache und Standardsprache für ziemlich unscharf. In der Umgangssprache existiert das Wort definitiv, ob man es auch zur Standardsprache zählen kann, will ich nicht beurteilen.

Deutsch ist eine lebende Sprache. Das heißt, sie verändert sich ständig. Was gestern noch als falsch galt (»Sinn machen« statt »sinnvoll sein«), ist heute Bestandteil der gehobenen Standardsprache. Ich kann nicht in die Zukunft sehen, aber es ist durchaus denkbar, dass sich »manchmals« weiter verbreitet, und dann wird es irgendwann mal auch durch die Aufnahme in den Duden ganz offiziell als »standardsprachlich« geadelt.

**Sagen die Leute das tatsächlich so?**
Ja. Vielleicht nicht alle, und vielleicht nicht überall, aber das Wort wird definitiv von einer Gruppe von nicht vernachlässigbarer Größe verwendet

Comment: Öfters ist auch im Norden gebräuchlich. Genau wie nochmals.

Answer (score -1):

Nein, das Wort gibt es nicht. Auch die Google Suche zeigt dazu nur verhältnismäßig  wenige Treffer. Meist einfach nur ein Schreibfehler oder ein Fehler in der Sprache. Korrektes Deutsch ist es auf jeden Fall nicht, auch nicht umgangssprachlich.

Comment: Dafür, dass es Wort angeblich nicht geben soll findet Google bei der Suche nach "manchmals -manchmal" ganz schön viele Treffer, nämlich 12.600.

Comment: Nur, weil es oft verwendet wird, ist es noch lange nicht richtig. Auf der anderen Seite gibt es bei Sprache keine "Naturgesetze", sondern bestenfalls Konventionen. Mein persönliches Sprachempfinden sagt mir, dass "manchmals" falsch ist - genauso wie "frühs" oder "späts", nicht aber wie "öfters", was meinem Empfinden nach korrekt ist. Allerdings denke ich, dass "persönliches Sprachempfinden" genauso wenig ein Kriterium für die Beurteilung sein sollte wie die Anzahl von Google-Treffern...